# How to get repeated value from google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

From a ROW I need to get the repeated value.

Example:

**A  B  C  D  E  <= Row

s q r s f  <=Value**

From the above row values how can I need a repeated value (i.e "s"). Could you help me get the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this formula in `F1`?

```
=UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A1:E1,ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(A1:E1,A1:E1)>1))))
```

Comment: Yep got the appropriate value, Thanks for you help :)